# Android GCM open app with data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I want to open a different activity when a user opens the app by pressing on the Push Notification.

This activity needs to be on top of the main. So when a user presses the Notification the stack should be:

Activity A -> Activity B.

Now i think their are 2 situations:

- The app is already running (so the main activity is already presented)
- The app is not running. (main activity is not presented)

So my question: How should i open the app, showing a new activity, with the main activity in its stack.

Code below only works when the app is already running (so the main activity is already in the stack).

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExtraActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    String appName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(icon)
    .setContentTitle(appName)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(message))
    .setContentText(message);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(uniqueId, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent;
manager = getPackageManager();
try {
  intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
  if (intent == null)
    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
  finish();
  startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```